# Crear una Lista y dentro de cada fila colocar una lista horizontal. Flutter

Tags: flutter

Estoy tratando de crear un lista y dentro de esa lista por cada registro crear otra lista horizontal, pero no logro realizarlo. Adjunto ejemplo.
Gracias!

Flutter.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Sin código, es muy difícil ayudarte. ¿Qué has intentado? Adjunta un [repro]. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Comment: Agrega un código con lo que has intentado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es sencillo solo debes crear un Listview.Builder y adentro del return vuelves a poner otro Listview.Builder pero con Axis.Horizontal te muestro el codigo de ejemplo

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExampleList extends StatelessWidget {

const ExampleList({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
   appBar: AppBar(
     title: const Text('List'),
   ),
   body: SizedBox(
     child: SizedBox(
       width: double.infinity,
       child: ListView.builder(
         itemCount: 3,
         itemBuilder: (context, index) {
           return _ListExamp1();
         },
       ),
     ),
   ),
  );
 }
}

 class _ListExamp1 extends StatelessWidget {
   const _ListExamp1({
     Key? key,
   }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      height: 200,
      color: Colors.yellow,
      child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        itemCount: 6,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return const _List2();
         },
       ),
    );
   }
  }

  class _List2 extends StatelessWidget {
   const _List2({
     Key? key,
   }) : super(key: key);

   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        height: 50,
        width: 150,
        color: Colors.blue,
        child: const Text('data'),
      );
    }
  }
```

Espero y te funcione

Comment: El unico cambio que tuve que hacer en el código fue envolver el Scaffold en un MaterialApp, Muchas gracias!!